# Problem regarding attribute error in Kivy

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from Help import help
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog


class Begins(MDApp):
   def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Yellow"
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    screen = Screen()
    self.id_v = Builder.load_string(help)
    screen.add_widget(self.id_v)

    return screen

class My(FloatLayout):
   scr = ObjectProperty(None)
   def data(self):
       username = self.id_v.user.text
       password = self.id_v.passw.text
       if username == "MD" and password == "kivy":
          print('ok')
       else:
          dial=MDDialog(text='Opps Wrong!')
          dial.open()


Begins().run()
```

and here is my kivy file

```
   help = """
   Screen:
   id:scr    
   user:user
   passw:passw
   FloatLayout:    
    
    MDTextField:
        id: user
        hint_text : "Enter your Name"
        helper_text : "Have u forget it?"
        helper_text_mode : "on_focus"
        icon_right : "android"
        icon_right_color : app.theme_cls.primary_color
        size_hint_x :None
        width : '300'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.6}
    MDTextField:    
        id: passw
        hint_text : "Enter your Password"
        helper_text : "Got it?"
        helper_text_mode : "on_focus"
        icon_right : "key"
        icon_right_color : app.theme_cls.primary_color
        size_hint_x :None
        width : '300'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        pass: True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"Log in"
        pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.4}
        on_release:root.data()

"""
```

It is showing AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'data'
This is one of the problem and other problem is whenever i am importing this to another file by default it is running first,so where to use if_name_=="*main*": such as i am using this screen as login button.

Answer (score 0):

Protect your `run()` call like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Begins().run()
```

In your `kv`, the line:

```
on_release:root.data()
```

is calling a `data()` method of the `root` object of that `kv` rule. It appear that the `root` of that rule is `Screen`. From the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#value-expressions-on-property-expressions-ids-and-reserved-keywords):

> root
>
> This keyword is available only in rule definitions and represents
> the root widget of the rule (the first instance of the rule):
>
> <MyWidget>:
>
> ```
> custom: 'Hello world'
> Button:
>     text: root.custom
> ```

Comment: So, How to resolve this data() issue?  How to call function from python file to kivy?

Answer (score 0):

After utilizing many hours I just figure out that instead of

```
on_release:root.data()
```

it should refer to it by

```
on_release:app.data()
```

*and just move data function in App class.

Comment: Odd that it works, since the `data()` method is not in your `App` class. It appears to be in your `My` class

Comment: yah,you are right i have just moved data() in App class.